# Conditional replacement of objects in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes `df_1` and `df_2`. Both have an index `datetimecode`which is a `pd.datetime64` object, and a `temp` column. I want to iterate through `df_1` and replace all the NaN temperature values with the corresponding temp from `'df_2'`.

Something like this:

```
for index, row in df_1.iterows():
      row['temp'] = df_2[index]['temp'] if row['temp'] ==np.nan
```

but this is invalid sytax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df_1.fillna(df_2, inplace=True)
```

or

```
df_1.loc[df_1.temp.isnull(), 'temp'] = df_2.temp
```

---

***demonstration***

```
tidx = pd.date_range('2016-03-31', periods=5)
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(temp=[1, np.nan, 3, np.nan, 5]), tidx)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(temp=np.arange(11, 16)), tidx)

df_1.fillna(df_2)
```

[image]

```
df_1.loc[df_1.temp.isnull(), 'temp'] = df_2.temp

df_1
```

[image]

Comment: I have implemented the first method, and there is an error at the `df_1.fillna` statement which says `pandas.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError` 
The error is inconsistent - it depends on the time period selected but i can't see anything causing it......

Comment: ...In fact, the error is completely intermittent and apparently random when running the same data - so it looks like there is some instability in this solution?

Comment: well then... good thing I gave you two solutions ;-)  I'm looking into the warning though.  That is a tad troubling

Comment: Ha! Yes a good thing. But your second solution isn't working for me at the moment, it gives this error: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`.

Comment: My bad! There was a duplicated data item in `df_2` (because the imported timecodes had daylight savings) which caused the indexing error (though strangely, only sometimes). Both of your methods work well.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'temp': [1,2,3,np.nan,5,np.nan,7]})
   temp
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   3.0
3   NaN
4   5.0
5   NaN
6   7.0

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'temp': [8,9,10,11,12,13,14]})
   temp
0     8
1     9
2    10
3    11
4    12
5    13
6    14

df_1.temp.fillna(df_2['temp'], inplace=True)

   temp
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   3.0
3  11.0
4   5.0
5  13.0
6   7.0

   temp
0     8
1     9
2    10
3    11
4    12
5    13
6    14
```

Comment: @Brian Well we both answered exactly in the same time apparently. Just a few seconds apart probably...

Comment: Thank you both @Brian  - sorry I can't accept both answers!